# g++ compilier how to include boost::regex

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I've installed boost, so i'm trying to run compiler like this:`g++ -LC:\MinGW\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib -lboost_regex-mgw49-mt-1_55 test.cpp`

My programm `test.cpp` is not very complicated:

```
#include <iostream>         
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;    
  boost::regex rex("[test]");
}
```

I'm of course failed: `error: 'boost' has not been declared`. I can't understand what I must write in my `test.cpp` file next to `#include <iostream>`? `#include <boost>` doesn't work, i'm getting error `fatal error: boost: No such file or directory`.
`#include <boost/regex.hpp>` also yield this error, maybe `#include <boost_regex-mgw49-mt-1_55>`? But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include regex.hpp in your main. You hint that you tried to, but it apparently didn't work.

Make sure regex.hpp is where you tell the compiler it is relative to one of your search directories. It's not good enough to tell the compiler to include boost/regex.hpp, the file has to actually exist where the compiler is looking for it to be able to find it.

You will need to copy that file from wherever you downloaded it to somewhere the compiler will know to look for it. Once you do that, it should find it and that error should go away.

Also note that the same applies to the object file you're trying to link in. If the linker can't find that file, you'll just get a linker error once you clear up this compiler error.

Comment: Thanks! So, i've found regex.hpp in 'C:\MinGW\boost_1_55_0\boost'. Copied it to C:\MinGW\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib and even C:\MinGW\boost_1_55_0\stage. I've added <include regex.hpp> in test.cpp but still error.

Comment: You don't want a header file in a lib directory. The compiler has different search directories for the linker and the compiler. You may need to specify a new search directory for the compiler, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't just create a boost folder inside your project source folder and put regex.hpp there. Then "#include "boost/regex.hpp" should work.

Comment: I have explained what you need to do. Use the -I option to add search directories for the compiler.

Comment: Even if i try to run g++ test.cpp -I/C:/MinGW/boost_1_55_0/boost i'm getting error. In this directory i have endeed regex.hpp. I've typed "#include <regex.hpp>". But  fatal error: regex.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: You have an extra slash between -I and C:. Other than that, there's really nothing else I can see. That error means the compiler cannot find the hpp file.